# Boostrap lightbox not working as expected

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a functional lightbox to work on my page using code from 'bootply.com/' but it does't seem to work. It works as a link, but not as a lightbox. I get an error relating to the Javascript which states '$ is not defined', but I can't seem to locate the issue. I'm simply replicating the code, so not sure what I'm missing!

```
  <script type="text/JavaScript">
$('.thumbnail').click(function(){
    $('.modal-body').empty();
    var title = $(this).parent('a').attr("title");
    $('.modal-title').html(title);
    $($(this).parents('div').html()).appendTo('.modal-body');
    $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
});
```

http://www.bootply.com/71401

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you need to include the jQuery library into your HTML. Bootstrap javascript library depends on it afaik and you're using it in your script.. `$('DomElement')`

Answer (score 0):

you have to include jQuery.

if you have jQuery lib then

`<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>`

or

use jQuery CDN

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the jQuery library..

Include this in the top of your HTML before you attempt to use the `$`

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively you can download the jQuery library and reference it yourself.

This should resolve the issue.

Comment: That's great, thanks for that. It no no longer brings up an error in the console, but the images still open in a new window and not a lightbox. I've copied the exact code, so not sure why? Do I need to include anything else?

Comment: @JamesPardigan Im not sure i follow, from the looks of your code, you're using modals instead of ligthbox.. take a look here for an example : http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/#image-gallery